# "ImportError: cannot import name StanfordNERTagger" in NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I'm unable to import the NER Stanford Tagger in NLTK. This is what I have done:

Downloaded the java code from [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml) 
and added an environment variable `STANFORD_MODELS` with the path to the folder where the java code is stored.

That should be sufficient according to the information that is provided on the NLTK site. It says:

"Tagger models need to be downloaded from http://nlp.stanford.edu/software and the STANFORD_MODELS environment variable set (a colon-separated list of paths)."

Would anybody be kind enough to help me, please?

EDIT: The downloaded folder is located at /Users/-----------/Documents/JavaJuno/stanford-ner-2015-04-20 and contains these files:

```
LICENSE.txt         lib             ner.sh              stanford-ner-3.5.2-javadoc.jar
NERDemo.java            ner-gui.bat         sample-conll-file.txt       stanford-ner-3.5.2-sources.jar
README.txt          ner-gui.command         sample-w-time.txt       stanford-ner-3.5.2.jar
build.xml           ner-gui.sh          sample.ner.txt          stanford-ner.jar
classifiers         ner.bat             sample.txt
```

Then I have added an environment variable STANFORD_MODELS:

```
os.environ["STANFORD_MODELS"] = "/Users/-----------/Documents/JavaJuno/stanford-ner-2015-04-20"
```

Calling from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger yields the error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-356-f4287e573edc> in <module>()
----> 1 from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger

ImportError: cannot import name StanfordNERTagger
```

Also in case that this may be relevant, this is what is in my nltk.tag folder:

```
__init__.py api.pyc     crf.py      hmm.pyc     senna.py    sequential.pyc  stanford.py tnt.pyc
__init__.pyc    brill.py    crf.pyc     hunpos.py   senna.pyc   simplify.py stanford.pyc    util.py
api.py      brill.pyc   hmm.py      hunpos.pyc  sequential.py   simplify.pyc    tnt.py      util.pyc
```

EDIT2: I have managed to import the NER Tagger, by using:

```
from nltk.tag.stanford import NERTagger
```

but now when calling an example call from the NLTK website, I get:

```
In [360]: st = NERTagger('english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LookupError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-360-0c0ab770b0ff> in <module>()
----> 1 st = NERTagger('english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz')

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/tag/stanford.pyc in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    158 
    159     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 160         super(NERTagger, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    161 
    162     @property

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/tag/stanford.pyc in __init__(self, path_to_model, path_to_jar, encoding, verbose, java_options)
     40                 self._JAR, path_to_jar,
     41                 searchpath=(), url=_stanford_url,
---> 42                 verbose=verbose)
     43 
     44         self._stanford_model = find_file(path_to_model,

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/__init__.pyc in find_jar(name, path_to_jar, env_vars, searchpath, url, verbose)
    595                     (name, url))
    596     div = '='*75
--> 597     raise LookupError('\n\n%s\n%s\n%s' % (div, msg, div))
    598 
    599 ##########################################################################

LookupError: 

===========================================================================
  NLTK was unable to find stanford-ner.jar! Set the CLASSPATH
  environment variable.

  For more information, on stanford-ner.jar, see:
    <http://nlp.stanford.edu/software>
===========================================================================
```

So I have incorrectly set the environment variable. Can anybody help me with that?

Comment: have you tried either of these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555312/instantiating-and-using-stanfordtagger-within-nltk

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23861355/how-to-install-and-invoke-stanford-nertagger

Comment: I have only seen the first question, which wasn't helpful. The second question is basically my problem, the answer says that this needs to be done: "...put it[the downloaded Stanford folder] in the place the path indicates and change the directory name in the path described in the NLKT document to whatever name one wants to use for the directory", but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: I think he may be talking about doing what is suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344916/trouble-importing-stanford-pos-tagger-into-nltk could you post the code you're using?

Comment: I have edited the question with the code.

Comment: I have managed to import the tagger, but I seem to have set the environment variable incorrectly, because python cant find the jar files, see EDIT2.

Comment: I'm not fully sure on how to set the class path but I think this might do it: os.environ["CLASSPATH"] = /Users/-----------/Documents/JavaJuno/stanford-ner-2015-04-20/stanford-ner-3.5.2.jar

Comment: Thanks for your help, but unfortunately it still doesn't work. I still get the same error.

Comment: I also tried setting the CLASSPATH variable with just /Users/-----------/Documents/JavaJuno/stanford-ner-2015-04-20, but still get the same error. I have noticed that you can also supply a path_to_jar in the NERTagger constructor(NERTagger(,path_to_jar = "/Users/-----------/Documents/JavaJuno/stanford-ner-2015-04-20"), but when I use the path to the file where the jar-file is included I get the error: ValueError: Could not find stanford-ner.jar jar file at /Users/-----------/Documents/JavaJuno/stanford-ner-2015-04-20, but the file is certainly there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I worked it out.

1. set the STANFORD_MODELS as you did # I learnt from you, thx!
2. import nltk.tag.stanford as st
3. tagger = st.StanfordNERTagger(PATH_TO_GZ, PATH_TO_JAR) # here PATH_TO_GZ and PATH_TO_JAR are the FULL path to where I store the file "all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz" and the file "stanford-ner.jar"
4. now the tagger is usable. # try tagger.tag(‘Rami Eid is studying at Stony Brook University in NY’.split())

It has nothing to do with CLASSPATH.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Step 3 gives me the following error:


`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'StanfordNERTagger'`

Comment: It was written a year ago. Maybe the new version changed the name? Try look at the documentation of nltk.tag.stanford and see what is the name of the component that do the NER tagging.

Comment: How exactly did you set the STANFORD_MODELS variables?

Comment: @MERose `export STANFORD_MODELS="the/complete/directory/path"`

Comment: where can I find PATH_TO_GZ and PATH_TO_JAR?

Answer (score 4):

try this approach:

```
from nltk.tag.stanford import StanfordNERTagger
st = StanfordNERTagger('/usr/share/stanford-ner/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz', '/usr/share/stanford-ner/stanford-ner.jar')
st.tag('Rami Eid is studying at Stony Brook University in NY'.split())
```

worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach:

```
    from nltk.tag.stanford import NERTagger
    import os
    java_path = "/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java.exe"
    os.environ['JAVAHOME'] = java_path
    st = NERTagger('../ner-model.ser.gz','../stanford-ner.jar')
```

The NERTagger takes two arguments: the path to the model file and the path to the jar file.

Answer (score 1):

```
from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger
import os

java_path = "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java.exe"

os.environ['JAVAHOME'] = "JAVA_PATH" #this java path you get from command 'echo %PATH%'in terminal 

st = StanfordNERTagger('/usr/share/stanford ner/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz','/usr/share/stanford-ner/stanford-ner.jar',encoding='utf-8') #download 'stanford-postagger-2017-06-09' package and give the paths for.gz &.jar
```