# Different result in StanfordNERTagger in python3.5 - Stanford-ner-2015-12-09

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I tried to run a sample sentence:

```
from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger
_model_filename = r'D:/standford/stanford-ner-2015-12-09/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz'

_path_to_jar = r'D:/standford/stanford-ner-2015-12-09/stanford-ner.jar'

st = StanfordNERTagger(model_filename=_model_filename, path_to_jar=_path_to_jar)

st.tag('Rami Eid is studying at Stony Brook University in NY'.split())
```

My output was as below in python:

> [('Rami', 'PERSON'), ('Eid', 'PERSON'), ('is', 'O'), ('studying',
>   'O'), ('at', 'O'), ('Stony', 'ORGANIZATION'), ('Brook',
>   'ORGANIZATION'), ('University', 'ORGANIZATION'), ('in', 'O'), ('NY',
>   'O')]

while I was expected NY also selected as location based on this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23861355/how-to-install-and-invoke-stanford-nertagger).

I tried another example as below:

```
st.tag('Ali is living in London.'.split())
```

the result was as below which was correct.

> [('Ali', 'PERSON'), ('is', 'O'), ('living', 'O'), ('in', 'O'),
>   ('London.', 'LOCATION')]

Do you have any idea why it didn't recognize NY as location in first sentence?

I am using visual studio 2015, Python 3.5, Stanford-ner-2015-12-09

Comment: Ad a full to your sentence. No model is perfect =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stanford NER tool is trained on properly formatted news text so punctuation is quite important. From the [docs](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml):

> Stanford NER is a Java implementation of a Named Entity Recognizer.
>   Named Entity Recognition (NER) labels sequences of words in a text
>   which are the names of things, such as person and company names, or
>   gene and protein names. It comes with well-engineered feature
>   extractors for Named Entity Recognition, and many options for defining
>   feature extractors. Included with the download are good named entity
>   recognizers for English, particularly for the 3 classes (PERSON,
>   ORGANIZATION, LOCATION), and we also make available on this page
>   various other models for different languages and circumstances,
>   including models trained on just the CoNLL 2003 English training data.

From the [CoNLL 2003 doc](http://www.cnts.ua.ac.be/conll2003/ner/):

> The English data is a collection of news wire articles from the
>   Reuters Corpus. The annotation has been done by people of the
>   University of Antwerp. Because of copyright reasons we only make
>   available the annotations. In order to build the complete data sets
>   you will need access to the Reuters Corpus. It can be obtained for
>   research purposes without any charge from NIST.

By adding the fullstop to the example sentence, you should get your desired output, but still no model is perfect =)

```
alvas@ubi:~$ export STANFORDTOOLSDIR=$HOME
alvas@ubi:~$ export CLASSPATH=$STANFORDTOOLSDIR/stanford-ner-2015-12-09/stanford-ner.jar
alvas@ubi:~$ export STANFORD_MODELS=$STANFORDTOOLSDIR/stanford-ner-2015-12-09/classifiers
alvas@ubi:~$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Jul  5 2016, 12:43:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger
>>> st = StanfordNERTagger('english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz')
>>> sent = 'Rami Eid is studying at Stony Brook University in NY .'.split()
>>> st.tag(sent)
[('Rami', 'PERSON'), ('Eid', 'PERSON'), ('is', 'O'), ('studying', 'O'), ('at', 'O'), ('Stony', 'ORGANIZATION'), ('Brook', 'ORGANIZATION'), ('University', 'ORGANIZATION'), ('in', 'O'), ('NY', 'LOCATION'), ('.', 'O')]
>>> sent = 'Rami Eid is studying at Stony Brook University in NY'.split()
>>> st.tag(sent)
[('Rami', 'PERSON'), ('Eid', 'PERSON'), ('is', 'O'), ('studying', 'O'), ('at', 'O'), ('Stony', 'ORGANIZATION'), ('Brook', 'ORGANIZATION'), ('University', 'ORGANIZATION'), ('in', 'O'), ('NY', 'O')]
```

Comment: Thanks dude for explanation.

Comment: I'm glad the answer helped.